# int variable/parameter cannot be resolved to a type, variable declared publicly

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement

[The red underlined portion is the error. The specific error is "magnitude cannot be resolved to a type."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU5Ny.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to images. Use the [edit] link to copy past your code *as text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify type of parameter:

```
public String getDescription(String magnitude){
    ....
}
```

In this case it is `String`. This is just an example.

If you want to use class' `magnitude` field you do not need to accept anything as parameter then.

```
public String getDescription(){
    ....
}
```

If you want to assign it from parameter:

```
public String getDescription(String magnitude){
    this.magnitude = magnitude;
}
```